# The order of a quantity

Tags: terminology

I am reading Whittaker's Analytical Dynamics. He often times talks of quantities of first order. How do you define the order of a quantity?

Comment: I think by converting to scientific notation and grabbing the power of the $10$.  The first order would be $10^0$ quantities like $5.0 \times 10^0$.  All quantities $q$ that are such that $|q|< 10$ approximately.